# Developing Windows phone Applications with C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Im really confused here, I'm an Android developer and i want to develop windows phone applications.

after searching i found it possible to develop with C++ (and i love C++ btw)

but after i started on Eclipse (Kepler) i found that there is C++11 and older, and there are compatability problems between old version of C++ and newer ones

i want to know, can Windows phone be developed with C++11 or later, or not ?

and also i'm using Eclipse, and downloaded a MinGW compiler (and it's tool chain), will i need to download another things to be able to make a full C++ program (with .h and .cpp files)

and the last question, will i be able to make a windows phone application from eclipse or should i use Virtual Studio (and if so, which Virtual Studio supports developing windows phone applications with C++) ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Visual Studio; it's a [free download](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) and can be used for some Android and iOS development as well. Once Visual Studio is installed, you can create projects easily. There are basically three models of native code development for Windows Phone 8:

1. Silverlight UI with C++ business logic (similar to Java + C++ for Android)
2. Silverlight UI mixed with C++ and Direct3D rendering
3. Pure C++ with Direct3D (limited pretty much to games only, since there is no UI framework)

Visual Studio 2013 supports a lot of C++11; you can see the list (including upcoming support in Visual Studio 2015) [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx)